# Calling another JFrame panel by clicking button not working for me JAVA

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe

I want to do it so when I press the start button on my main screen panel it shows my build panel. I already had my buildPanel() going on but then I decided I wanted to add a main menu screen to start the game.

This is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.net.URL;

public class interfac extends JFrame {

    private JPanel pnlConverter;
    private JLabel MovePrompt;
    private JButton StartButton;
    private JPanel mainScreenpnl;

    public interfac() {
        
        //constructor - build out the general properties for the window
        super("Project");
        
        //give the window a size
        setSize(650,650);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        //call mainScreen()
        mainScreen();
        
        
        //add panel
        this.add(mainScreenpnl);
        
        //display window
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

When I call buildPanel() inside the action listener, it just stays in the mainSpreenpnl. I know the action listener is working after I tested it with a JOptionPane pop up.

```
public void mainScreen() {
    
    mainScreenpnl = new JPanel();
    StartButton = new JButton("Start Game");
    
    StartButton.addActionListener(new mainScreenbtnListener());
    
    mainScreenpnl.add(StartButton);
    
}

private class mainScreenbtnListener implements ActionListener {
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        buildPanel();
    }
}
```

buildPanel() has really ugly code from me so I'm just gonna add the necessary lines.

```
    public void buildPanel() {
        
        
        //create panel (container to hold objects)
        pnlConverter = new JPanel();

        //set foreground color (text color on labels)
        pnlConverter.setForeground(Color.black);
        
        //create label object
        MovePrompt = new JLabel("Pick a move: ");
        //set color for label
        MovePrompt.setForeground(Color.white);
        MovePrompt.setBounds(160, 300, 180, 100);
        MovePrompt.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        
        // no border layout
        pnlConverter.setLayout(null);

        pnlConverter.add(MovePrompt);
       
}
```

I have no idea why it's not working. Also, if you got any suggestions on how to optimize the code feel free to tell me. Thank you.

Comment: *any suggestions on how to optimize the code* - 1) variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some are correct, others are not. Be consistent! 2) Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Learn by example. All classes in the JDK follow this convention.  3) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 4) maybe start with the code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: The "ButtonDemo" will show how better structure the code. It will create a frame with some buttons. Modify the code to only display a single button and the ActionListener to display a JOptionPane. Once that works, then instead of displaying the JOPtionPane you can display a custom JDialog (not a JFrame).

Comment: At the beginning of buildPanel() I did `mainScreenpnl.setVisible(false);`, when I click the button it disappears which means the ActionListener is working, but my buildPanel() and everything in it don't show up, it's just a blank panel.

Comment: 1) you haven't implemented any of the suggestions. 2) not sure what you expect to happen. You create a new panel but never add it the the frame.

Comment: I'll just not do it I have no idea what I should do. I did change the variables to start with lowercase though, thanks for that advice.

Comment: *I have no idea what I should do* - what do you mean you have no idea? What is different in the frame that works versus the frame that doesn't work. In the frame that works you actually add the panel to the frame. In the frame that works you don't use a null layout. I gave a couple of suggestions. I also suggested that you start over and use better structured code from the tutorial.

Comment: The problem is beginners try to write the entire application all at once without debugging as you go. Start small! Display a frame with a button. Then add an ActionListener to display an empty frame. Then you add a panel to the empty frame. When/if it stops working then you know what you just changed, so you know what area of code to fix. If you write all the code at once you have no idea where the code falls apart.